# MSBuild: Cannot build Visual Studio 2008 project with spaces in solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Found online the way to use MSBuild to build a Visual Studio 2008 project within a solution, using the following syntax:

```
msbuild Solution.sln /t:"ProjectName:Rebuild"
```

However my project name contains a space, so I've tried:

```
msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Project Two:Rebuild"

msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Project Two":Rebuild

msbuild Solution.sln /t:""Project Two":Rebuild"

msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Project Two" /t:Rebuild
```

It definitely has to do with quotes. Either it takes the Rebuild as part of the project name and fails, complains about syntax, or if Rebuild is separated out it rebuilds the entire solution as a separate target. If I just remove the Rebuild target from the command it works fine.

```
msbuild Solution.sln /t:"Project Two"
```

But that means I cannot select Build or Rebuild in my script, I have to live with the default.

Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: hmmm...Have you tried msbuild Solution.sln /t:""Project Two":Rebuild"?

Comment: Syntax is `MSBuild.exe [Switches] [ProjectFile]`.  So it is msbuild /t:Rebuild "Project Two".

Comment: Can you just execute build on the specific project, rather than on solution? I.e.: `msbuild "Project Two.proj" /t:Rebuild`

Comment: If I do not load the solution, the project does not build on its own because of dependencies on other projects. At the same time I cannot build the entire solution because there will be errors in projects I do not require. I'd like to see this corrected of course, but its not mine to fix.

Comment: A simple test solution/project builds just fine using, say, `msbuild MySolution.sln /t:"Class Library2:Rebuild"` from the command prompt (`cmd.exe` that is). I'm using VS 2013 however.